# If condition within Array in React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, rxjs

I have an array of value pairs as below,

```
const servingType = [
    {value: 'Hot', label: 'Served Hot'},
    {value: 'Cold', label: 'Served Cold'},
    {value: 'NA', label: 'Not Applicable'}
];
```

I have an object, which has a dynamic value for serving type. I have to check the serving type in the array and if it matches the value, and display the value in label of the array.
My Object :

```
const selectedItem = {
    menuItemID: selectItem.menuItemID || 100,
    menuItemName: 'Menu Item Name (M)',
    itemPrice: 100
    servingType:'Hot',
    preparationTime: 15
}
```

I tried the code as below but I couldn't figure it. Any thoughts on the below code.

```
<div>
  {servingType.map((serveType, id) => (
     if(servingType[serveType].value === selectedItem.servingType){
     {selectedItem.label}
  }                               
  ))}
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, I would suggest to use a `filter` function, not a `map` function, in this way:

```js
const servingType = [
    {value: 'Hot', label: 'Served Hot'},
    {value: 'Cold', label: 'Served Cold'},
    {value: 'NA', label: 'Not Applicable'}
];

const selectedItem = {
    menuItemID: "selectItem.menuItemID || 100",
    menuItemName: 'Menu Item Name (M)',
    itemPrice: 100,
    servingType: 'Hot',
    preparationTime: 15
};

console.log(servingType.filter(st => st.value === selectedItem.servingType)[0].label)
```

note: I transform `menuItemID` into string just because in my example `selectItem` is undefined.

**EDIT**

@Guy Incognito made another intersting solution by using `find` instead of `filter`:

```js
const servingType = [
        {value: 'Hot', label: 'Served Hot'},
        {value: 'Cold', label: 'Served Cold'},
        {value: 'NA', label: 'Not Applicable'}
    ];

    const selectedItem = {
        menuItemID: "selectItem.menuItemID || 100",
        menuItemName: 'Menu Item Name (M)',
        itemPrice: 100,
        servingType: 'Hot',
        preparationTime: 15
    };

    console.log(servingType.find(st => st.value === selectedItem.servingType).label)
```

Comment: `.find()` would be even better if there's only one expected result. It won't work inside JSX but they don't need to do it there, put the value in a variable after whatever needed is done and just print the variable.

Comment: Ciao, in my solution I supposed that there will be only one solution. Maybe my answer is limitated.

Comment: @GuyIncognito, could you please say how to use the .find() here for this scenario?

Comment: Glad to help you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: `servingType.find(st => st.value === selectedItem.servingType).label`

Comment: @GuyIncognito I added your solution to the answer because is intersting. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `()` to `{}` and then return the result. The inside of `()` expects a (React) object.

Also change `servingType[serveType].value` to `serveType.value` and change `{selectedItem.label}` to `serveType.label`

```
<div>
{
  servingType.map((serveType, id) => {
    if (serveType.value === selectedItem.servingType) {
      return serveType.label;
    }
    return null;
  });
}
<div>
```